# AzureML data_collector is not a known attribute of class ManagedOnlineDeployment and will be ignored

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service, azure-sdk

```
online_endpoint_name = "p2b-sample-endpoint"

# create an online endpoint
endpoint = ManagedOnlineEndpoint(
    name=online_endpoint_name,
    description="this is a sample online endpoint",
    auth_mode="key",
    tags={"foo": "bar"},
)
ml_client.online_endpoints.begin_create_or_update(endpoint)
blue_deployment = ManagedOnlineDeployment(
    name="blue",
    endpoint_name=online_endpoint_name,
    model=model,
    environment=env,
    code_configuration=CodeConfiguration(
        code="./", scoring_script="score.py"
    ),
    instance_type="Standard_DS2_v2",
    instance_count=1,
)
ml_client.online_deployments.begin_create_or_update(blue_deployment)
```

A warning is thrown

data_collector is not a known attribute of class <class 'azure.ai.ml._restclient.v2022_02_01_preview.models._models_py3.ManagedOnlineDeployment'> and will be ignored

PS: Actually the deployment fails and throws a different error,but I'm guessing if this warning created the main error

Answer (score 1):

**I tried in my environment and got the below results:**

> AzureML data_collector is not a known attribute of the class ManagedOnlineDeployment and will be ignored

The above statement is a warning it is not an error.

I followed this [MS-document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-deploy-online-endpoints?tabs=python) to create an online endpoint and deployments through python sdk.

**Code:**

```
from azure.ai.ml import MLClient
from azure.ai.ml.entities import (
    ManagedOnlineEndpoint,
    ManagedOnlineDeployment,
    Model,
    CodeConfiguration,
    Environment,
)
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential

subscription_id = "your-subscription-id"
resource_group = "yourresourcegrp"
workspace_name = "Testendpoint326"


credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
ml_client = MLClient(
    credential,
    subscription_id=subscription_id,
    resource_group_name=resource_group,
    workspace_name=workspace_name,
)
online_endpoint_name = "demo-endpoints326"

#create an online endpoint
endpoint = ManagedOnlineEndpoint(
    name=online_endpoint_name,
    description="this is a sample online endpoint",
    auth_mode="key",
    tags={"foo": "bar"},
)
ml_client.online_endpoints.begin_create_or_update(endpoint)

model = Model(...endpoints\\online\\model-1\\model\\sklearn_regression_model.pkl")
env = Environment(
    conda_file="...endpoints\\online\\model-1\\environment\\conda.yml",
    image="mcr.microsoft.com/azureml/openmpi4.1.0-ubuntu20.04:latest",
)

blue_deployment = ManagedOnlineDeployment(
    name="blue",
    endpoint_name=online_endpoint_name,
    model=model,
    environment=env,
    code_configuration=CodeConfiguration(
        code="...endpoints\\online\\model-1\\onlinescoring", scoring_script="score.py"
    ),
    instance_type="Standard_DS2_v2",
    instance_count=1,
)

ml_client.online_deployments.begin_create_or_update(
    deployment=blue_deployment)

print("Online deployments created successfully")
```

The above was executed successfully and created both endpoints and deployments.

**Output:**

```
Check: endpoint demo-endpoints326 exists
Uploading onlinescoring (0.0 MBs): 100%|########################################################| 4999/4999 [00:01<00:00, 4969.10it/s] 


Uploading sklearn_regression_model.pkl (< 1 MB): 100%|###############################################| 756/756 [00:00<00:00, 2.88kB/s] 

#warning
data_collector is not a known attribute of class <class 'azure.ai.ml._restclient.v2022_02_01_preview.models._models_py3.ManagedOnlineDeployment'> and will be ignored
Online deployments created successfully
```

[image]

**Workspace:**

[image]